# Why do "curl 0.0.0.0" and "nc 0.0.0.0 80" work?

Tags: curl, networking, localhost, ip-address, netcat

When I type `curl 0.0.0.0` and `nc 0.0.0.0 80` in bash, I can connect to the HTTP server running on localhost.

Is `0.0.0.0` the same as `127.0.0.1`? Why? When I try to search `0.0.0.0` in Google, it seems to be an invalid IP address. Why does it point to localhost?

Comment: in some ways, if you understand that 0.0.0.0 actually references a non-routeable address, then this is a surprisingly deep  question... I'm hoping there will be more answers on the way.  When you read the RFC, it sais 0.0.0.0 is non-routeable, but for most programmers, 0.0.0.0 is the easiest way to reach their running application bound to a port, and 127.0.0.1 may not work all the time.

Answer (score 1):

0.0.0.0 is a valid IP address and it does not remap to 127.0.0.1. curl and nc use that address just as they would use any other IPv4 numerical address.

A lot of tools and systems do not support that as an address since it equals to a binary all-zero 32bit pattern which is treated as magic in a lot of APIs.

Sort of related: port 0 also works with a similar set of caveats.

Comment: can you post a link to RFC which proves 0.0.0.0 to be a valid IP address?

Comment: well, there's no RFC saying that it *is* special, which is my point.